# CSS3 Fullscreen Slideshow w/ Static navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

So I am using a CSS3 Fullscreen Slideshow thanks to this guy [here](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index2.html) and I want to place my navigation on top of it. But when I did that, it fades along with the slideshow.

How can I change the code so it does not interact with the background? So that the navigation is static and not interacting with the fullscreen slideshow? I have an example of it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ucnedi/2oyrgtgf/).

HTML of NAV

```
          <div class="nav">
        <nnedi>Nnedimma</nnedi><br><nnedi>Ugochukwu</nnedi>
        <ul class="nav cl-effect-1">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="china.html" target="content">China</a></li>
            <li><a href="light.html" target="content">Light</a></li>
            <li><a href="travel.html" target="content">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content">Cyanotypes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content">Self</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content">School</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content">Vector Portraits</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content">About</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the following line in the Modernizr function and remove

```
nav|"e=d.html5elements||"abbr|article|aside|audio|canvas|datalist|details|figcaption|figure|footer|header|hgroup|mark|meter|nav|output|progress|section|summary|time|video
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 <body>
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
<li><span>Image 01</span></li>
<li><span>Image 02</span></li>
<li><span>Image 03</span></li>
<li><span>Image 04</span></li>
<li><span>Image 05</span></li>
<li><span>Image 06</span></li>
</ul>

<div class="nav">
<nnedi>Stacy<br/>Cool</nnedi>
<ul class="nav cl-effect-1">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="china.html" target="content">China</a></li>
  <li><a href="light.html" target="content">Light</a></li>
  <li><a href="travel.html" target="content">Travel</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="content">Cyanotypes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="content">Self</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="content">School</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="content">Vector Portraits</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="content">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/2oyrgtgf/8/